# Image saved from URL is partly gray

Tags: image, url, inputstream, fileoutputstream

Im writing a program that saves images from the Internet, but some of the images end up partly gray. Or well its just really the icon that is gray because if I open the image its not gray at all.

Here is the method that I use to save the image:

```
public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;

    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, length);
    }

    is.close();
    os.close();
}
```

I believe the problem is that Im closing the streams before the image has been written completely. Is there any way I can check if its done or something?

Comment: The code looks fine. What do you mean by "the icon"? Could you be serving the image/icon before it is completely written? You want to wait until this saveImage method has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour occurs when you have the folder open in windows explorer and refresh at the same time your code is writing the image. Windows will try to create a thumbnail. In the first part of the file all "headerinfo" is stored, so windows will know how big the image is and all that. Because not all data is present the thumbnail will become gray for that section.

Comment: Ah ya you were right, I feel so silly for asking it here now >_<

Comment: don't feel silly. It took me some time too to discover this behaviour :)